# Conditional exercise addWithSurcharge

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I can't figure why b arguments greater than 20 don't work here. See results

Exercise:
Write a function addWithSurcharge that adds two amounts with surcharge. For each amount less than or equal to 10, the surcharge is 1. For each amount greater than 10 and less than or equal to 20, the surcharge is 2. For each amount greater than 20, the surcharge is 3.

Example: addWithSurcharge(10, 30) should return 44.

```
function addWithSurcharge(a,b) {
let sur1 = 0
if (a <= 10) {
sur1 = 1;
} else if (10 < a <= 20) {
sur1 = 2;
} else if (a > 20) {
sur1 = 3;
}

let sur2 = 0
if (b <= 10) {
sur2 = 1;
} else if (10 < b <= 20) {
sur2 = 2;
} else if (b > 20) {
sur2 = 3; 
}

return a + b + sur1 + sur2;
}
```

[image: results]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issue

The reason is that you condition `else if (10 < a <= 20)` evaluates to **true**.

1. `10 < a` will be evaluated to **true**
2. `true <= 20` will be evaluated to **true**.

So the number will evaluated as boolean and every number greater than 0 evaluates to true. That's the reason why `true <= 20` evaluates to **true**

You can check this by this snippet

```js
console.log(true <= 20)
console.log(true <= 0)
console.log(true <= -3)
```

### Solution

To define a range you should use the && operator like this

```
 else if (10 < b && b <= 20)
```

**Then it will**

1. check `if 10 < 30` evaluate to **true**
2. check `if 30 <= 20` evaluate to **false**
3. `true && false` will evaluate to **false**

```js
function addWithSurcharge(a,b) {
let sur1 = 0
if (a <= 10) {
sur1 = 1;
} else if (10 < a && a <= 20) {
sur1 = 2;
} else if (a > 20) {
sur1 = 3;
}

let sur2 = 0
if (b <= 10) {
sur2 = 1;
} else if (10 < b && b <= 20) {
sur2 = 2;
} else if (b > 20) {
sur2 = 3; 
}

return a + b + sur1 + sur2;
}

console.log(addWithSurcharge(10,30))
```

Comment: Nice, I knew it was something with that line.